# Automatically updating QGIS attribute table to show newly added field

Tags: python, qgis

I have written a QGIS plugin that displays a user-specified shapefile, and then when the user chooses the option, the plugin automatically adds a new field to the shapefile, populates the new field with data, and then displays a copy of the shapefile based on the data in the new field.

The new copy of the shapefile shows the new field in the attribute table, but the attribute table of the original version is not refreshed and so does not show the new field.

Is there a way to "refresh" the link to the attribute table so that it shows the changes, without having to remove the shapefile from QGIS and then add it again?

Thanks

Comment: Try myLayer.updateFields() right after creating new fields?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @GermánCarrillo - that didn't work, so I have rewritten my question to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: So, what code are you using to add a new field to the Shapefile? Perhaps tha can help to figure the problem out.

Answer (score 2):

You can reload them all using:

```
QgsProject.instance().reloadAllLayers()
```

Comment: Worked for me on QGIS 3.10